# Sentinelsat Python API - download images after scihub IP Change

Tags: api, sentinelsat

I need download Sentinel-2 images. I used this code for like 2 years or more:

```
def download_S2_by_tile(tiles=[], initialDate='', finalDate='', downloads=''):
    """
    :param tiles: sentinel-2 tiles list, ex:  ['21LYD']
    :param initialDate: initial date of search and download, ex:  2021-03-01 (YYYY-MM-DD)
    :param finalDate: final date
    :param downloads: folder to save the files
    :return:
    """
    from collections import OrderedDict
    from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI

    # Sentinel-2 Copernicus credencials
    user = 'user'
    password = 'password'
    scihub = 'https://apihub.copernicus.eu/apihub'

    # Conecting API
    api = SentinelAPI(user, password, scihub)

    # converting Date intel format
    date_i = '{}{}{}'.format(initialDate[0:4], initialDate[5:7], initialDate[8:])
    date_f = '{}{}{}'.format(finalDate[0:4], finalDate[5:7], finalDate[8:])


    query_kwargs = {
        'platformname': 'Sentinel-2',
        'producttype': 'S2MSI1C',
        'date': (str(date_i), str(date_f)),
        'cloudcoverpercentage': (0, 80)}

    print(query_kwargs)
    products = OrderedDict()
    for tile in tiles:
        kw = query_kwargs.copy()
        kw['tileid'] = tile
        print(kw)
        pp = api.query(**kw)
        products.update(pp)
    if products != {}:
        print(dir(products))
        api.download_all(products=products, directory_path=downloads)

### Executing function to download images ### REPLICABLE EXAMPLE
download_S2_by_tile(tiles=['21LYD'], initialDate='2021-03-01', finalDate='2021-04-01', downloads=r'E:/GEO_Topo')
```

After SciHub IP change I already changed scihub server website on my code ('https://apihub.copernicus.eu/apihub'). Also, I am using latest version of sentinelsat published in GitHub (https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat.git), which has a few modifications in order to fix the scihub ip change bugs... But all that I get is this error:

```
>Fetching archival status: 100%|██████████| 6/6 [00:02<00:00,  2.08 products/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PYTHON/MG_Ag_Serv_2/geoProcessing/sentinel_stuffs.py", line 250, in <module>
    download_S2_by_tile(tiles=['21LYD'], initialDate='2021-03-01', finalDate='2021-04-01', downloads=r'E:/GEO_Topo')
  File "E:/PYTHON/MG_Ag_Serv_2/geoProcessing/sentinel_stuffs.py", line 248, in download_S2_by_tile
    api.download_all(products=products, directory_path=downloads)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\sentinelsat\sentinel.py", line 785, in download_all
    if not dl_task.exception() and dl_task.result():
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 456, in exception
    raise CancelledError()
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

How can I fix this? I am using Python from QGIS 3.8.

Comment: Time to change your password... Editing your post to delete it will still keep it in the edit history.

Comment: OMG, thank you for notice that. I will be more careful next time, changing my password right now.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the website. They have notices indicating the new IP addresses. Use those instead of the domain names.

Comment: I just could make it work... The issue is that in this new version of sentinelsat, the "products" parameter of "download_all" function needs to receive a simple python list of products ID (for instance: ['f72aacfe-c93f-4d40-b923-8ab6132129d7', 'a016d054-9192-44ef-a859-0853a1a4694a']) and not a OrderDirect object anymore (OrderedDict([('f72aacfe-c93f-4d40-b923-8ab6132129d7', {'title': 'S2B_MSIL1C_20210329T135109_N0209_R024_T21LYD_20210329T171205'..............])